# iOS Google sign in with SDK issue

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am doing google sign in using SDK for IOS app but i am getting below error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Your app is missing support for
>   the following URL schemes: com.logindemo.testdemo'

Any solution to resolve this error?

Comment: what is the bundle identifier for your app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross check your bundle ID in credentials of your Google app and IOS app.May be it is mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add URLSchemes to your app? Looking at the end of https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating